# Incorrect conversion from Duration to seconds

Tags: sql, date, time, teradata

My SQL code is giving incorrect conversion -

Code -

```
SELECT 
 ,begins as "START_TIME"
   , ends as "END_TIME"
   , (ends-begins) DAY(4) TO SECOND  as "Duration"
    ,EXTRACT(DAY  FROM Duration) * 86400 + EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM Duration) * 3600  + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Duration) * 60  + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Duration) as "Duration_in_sec"
FROM
TABLE_NAME
```

Output -

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|   START_TIME    |    END_TIME     |     Duration      | Duration_in_sec |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 9/20/2017 6:11  | 9/20/2017 13:45 | 0 07:33:05.000000 |         113,585 |
| 8/21/2017 10:58 | 8/28/2017 6:13  | 6 19:14:49.000000 |         674,089 |
| 9/20/2017 6:11  | 9/20/2017 11:45 | 0 05:34:14.000000 |         106,454 |
| 7/17/2017 0:57  | 7/17/2017 3:00  | 0 02:03:12.000000 |          93,792 |
| 7/23/2017 21:41 | 7/24/2017 2:41  | 0 04:59:28.000000 |         104,368 |
| 12/3/2016 15:20 | 12/4/2016 15:20 | 1 00:00:03.000000 |         172,803 |
| 8/24/2017 19:42 | 8/24/2017 20:30 | 0 00:48:27.000000 |          89,307 |
| 8/29/2017 23:07 | 8/30/2017 6:00  | 0 06:53:14.000000 |         111,194 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

**But I clearly know that the first record 7:33:05 (7 hours, 33 mins and 5 sec) = 27 185 seconds and not 113,585**

I suspect my logic is wrong but not sure where.

EDIT - 
Using

> EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM Duration) * 3600  + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Duration)
>   * 60  + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Duration) as "Duration_in_sec"

instead of

> **EXTRACT(DAY  FROM Duration)* 86400** + EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM Duration) *
>   3600  + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Duration) * 60  + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM
>   Duration) as "Duration_in_sec"

works fine for values <24 hours.

It seems to be a bug in the extract function.

PS - My overall aim is to divide the **Duration** column by an **int** column. In order to do that I am converting Duration to seconds. If there any other way to divide. Please let me know.

Comment: Btw, you can simply divide an interval, e.g. `duration / 5`

Comment: Duration is a Datetime column so it throws this error if I try to divide by an int. ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.

Comment: Based on your query `duration` is an Interval as result of a calculation, which can be divided or multiplied. Maybe it's related to the ODBC session, try .NET instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer -

The system was returning 1 even if the day was 0.

For example, for (0 07:33:05.000000)

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM Duration)
```

will return 1 and not 0 even though the days is 0. Hence 84600 seconds were being added to all calculations (Not sure why).

So I simply changed the logic to

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM Duration)-1
```

Comment: You calculation works fine for me, if this actually returns 1it's a strange bug. What's your exact Teradata release (from `dbc.DBCInfoV`)?

Comment: I am using 15.10.03.07b

Comment: Hmm, it's correct on 15.10.02.06. In your example data `1 00:00:03.000000` returns `172,803` which is 2*86400 to much.

Answer (score 0):

try that ,

```
 SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, @start, @end)) + ' Days '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, @start, @end) % 24) + ' Hours '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mi, @start, @end) % 60) + ' Minutes '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(ss, DATEADD(s, @x, CONVERT(DATETIME2, '0001-
     01-01')))) + ' Seconds'
```

than multiply days with 86400  for seconds and hours with 3600 and minute with 60 and get sum of all.